# Wait for element to be clickable by accessibility ID

Tags: c#, selenium, appium

I am trying to do a wait for element to be visible before I try to click it. My tests fail with `NoSuchElementException` if I don't wait. Right now I am doing a wait by text but I want to be able to wait for the `accessibilityId`. I noticed that `accessibilityId` is not an option in `By`. How do I handle it?

```
_driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capability);
var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver,new TimeSpan(0,0,0,15));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(
     By.XPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Bypass Sign In (Testing Only)']")));
_driver.FindElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Bypass Sign In (Testing Only)']").Click();;
```

Update: I noticed that there is a MobileBy class with a By strategy for Accessibility Id however when I try to implement the wait with it my test fails immediately with a NoSuchElementException. Once I have waited long enough using the xpath and then do a click by _driver.FindByAccessibilityId it seems to recognize that button and click on it.

Failing Code below.
    'var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 45));

```
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("Button_SignIn")));

        _driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("Button_SignIn").Click();'
```

Working Code

```
`var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 45));

        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(
            By.XPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Bypass Sign In (Testing Only)']")));

        _driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("Button_SignIn").Click();`
```

Answer (score 4):

I just figured out that there is a MobileBy class in C# that has the AccessibilityId locator available as a By type but it didn't really do what I was expecting it to